# How to get only a few indexes of the data array?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm having trouble with the second iteration of this, take a look at the code below:

```
include ('rest.php');
include ('header.php');
include ('topo.php');
include ('menu.php');

$token = $_COOKIE['token'];

$table1 = "<div class='pai-forms'>
           <table id='calendarTable'>
            <tr>
              <th>Posição Array</th>
              <th>Nome</th>
              <th>Email</th>
              <th>CEP</th>
              <th>Numero</th>
              <th>Complemento</th>
              <th>Rua</th>
              <th>Logo</th>
              <th>Latitude</th>
              <th>Longitude</th>
              <th>Ativo</th>
              <th>Criado</th>
              <th>Atualizado</th>
            </tr>";

$table2 = " </table>
         </div>";

$dataSalons = wsListSalons($token);

echo $table1;
foreach ($dataSalons['data'] as $key => $value) {
  echo "<tr>";
  for ($i = 1; $i < 6; $i++) { // HERE IS THE PROBLEM
    echo "<td>".$value[$key]."</td>";
  }
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo $table2;

include ('footer.php');
```

I just wanna get the data of indexes 1 through 6 of the array, but when this line `for ($i = 1; $i < 6; $i++)` executes, it throws many of these errors:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\mcisalaositeadmin\list_salons.php on line 39
>   Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\mcisalaositeadmin\list_salons.php on line 39
>   Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\mcisalaositeadmin\list_salons.php on line 39
>   Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\mcisalaositeadmin\list_salons.php on line 39

What am I missing?

PS: I just tried it with a foreach loop, and it works, but it returns to me all of the indexes data. I just wanna get the indexes data 1 though 6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just break the loop if you hit an undefined index, e.g.

```
for ($i = 1; $i < 6; $i++) {
    if(!isset($value[$key]))
        break;
    echo "<td>" . $value[$key] . "</td>";
}
```

Or similar with a foreach loop:

```
foreach($value as $k => $v) {
    if($k == 5)
        break;
    echo "<td>" . $v . "</td>";
}
```

Or just take an `array_slice()` from your array and loop through the slice, then you don't have to check anything:

```
foreach(array_slice($value, 0, 6) as $v)
    echo "<td>" . $v . "</td>";
```

Comment: That's it man!!! The array_slice solution I have never seen before.. This worked perfectly.. Thank you very much..